# DatabaseError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression (Django)

Tags: python, sql, database, django, django-models

Django through a `DatabaseError` when I try to use a merged query set. My code is

```
assetsNetwork = Asset.objects.filter(client=myClient, module__label__in=network_label_list)
vulnsNetworkRaw = Vuln.objects.none()
for asset in assetsNetwork:
    vulnsNetworkRaw = vulnsNetworkRaw | asset.latest_vulns
    logging.debug("+++%s+++"%vulnsNetworkRaw)
```

The error message is

```
DatabaseError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

The .latest_vulns method is

```
@property
def latest_scan(self):
    from arachni.models import WebScan, Vulns as WebVuln
    my_module = self.module

    try:
        return Scan.objects.filter(assets__id=self.id, status='Audit Complete').latest('completed_Date')
    except:
        return Scan.objects.none()
@property
def latest_vulns(self):
    from arachni.models import WebScan, Vulns as WebVuln
    latest_scan = self.latest_scan
    return Vuln.objects.filter(scan=latest_scan, host=self.IP_Address)
```

Query:

```
2012-08-07 16:44:38 EDT STATEMENT:  SELECT "pegasus_vuln"."id", "pegasus_vuln"."nvt_id", "pegasus_vuln"."scan_id", "pegasus_vuln"."host", "pegasus_vuln"."port", "pegasus_vuln"."risk_factor", "pegasus_vuln"."cvss_score", "pegasus_vuln"."status", "pegasus_vuln"."change", "pegasus_vuln"."comment", "pegasus_vuln"."description", "pegasus_vuln"."solution", "pegasus_vuln"."_order" FROM "pegasus_vuln" WHERE (("pegasus_vuln"."host" = '192.168.2.251'  AND "pegasus_vuln"."scan_id" = 95 ) OR ("pegasus_vuln"."host" = '192.168.2.5'  AND "pegasus_vuln"."scan_id" =  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "pegasus_scan" U0)) OR ("pegasus_vuln"."host" = '10.1.10.244'  AND "pegasus_vuln"."scan_id" = 109 ) OR ("pegasus_vuln"."host" = '192.168.2.5'  AND "pegasus_vuln"."scan_id" =  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "pegasus_scan" U0)) OR ("pegasus_vuln"."host" = '192.168.2.248'  AND "pegasus_vuln"."scan_id" =  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "pegasus_scan" U0))) ORDER BY "pegasus_vuln"."_order" ASC LIMIT 21
2012-08-07 16:44:38 EDT ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

It successfully logs for several times, but gives an error also in the logging line. Could anybody help me? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the query that fails?

Comment: `asset.latest_vulns` is a list. Can you use `|` with a list?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: added the query by editing the original post. Thanks.

Comment: `|` cannot be used with lists. Are you sure you did not intend to use `or` operator instead of `|`?

Comment: @zaphod asset.lastest_vulns returns a queryset...

Comment: @PratikMandrekar asset.lastest_vulns returns a queryset...

Comment: Cool, querysets can be used with the `|` operator. Check your SQL nested statements which might be returning more than one rows where you have used `=` instead of `IN` wherever multiple rows are possible. Try executing the SQL independently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem have been solved weirdly. I added logging in `latest_vulns` to evaluate the query set, then everything works fine. It works even after I removed the logging.

Answer (score 1):

Check code like this in your SQL. You need to use IN operator if more than one result can be fetched from the nested SQL.

```
"pegasus_vuln"."scan_id" =  (SELECT U0."id" FROM "pegasus_scan" U0))
```

Comment: Can you at least validate the query by running it against the database you are using for testing?

Comment: The query might not be the issue, the data in your test database might be an issue.